# Unable to connect to oracle db from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I have created a database connection in eclipse using Oracle DB. I created a driver with the right username and password + the right listener port (I have checked it), as a host - localhost. So the whole URL looks like this:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE`.

But still, for some reason, I'm receiving "Ping failed" after I try to ping this connection. Then there's one thing: I'm choosing the SID database instance set to XE, but it automatically switches to Service Name: XE. Maybe this is the problem. I don't have some practical experience with this procedure, this is my first try to force my eclipse to connect to the Oracle DB. So I will appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this, perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you installed oracle driver in your eclipse?? and are you running oracle db at  your machine??

Comment: Also try with jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@localhost:1521:XE

Comment: Installed oracle driver in eclipse? I dont know exactly what do you mean, but I have pointed the right jar file to the eclipse. And yes oracle db is running on my machine, I can easily connect to it via cmd.  jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@localhost:1521:XE doesnt work also.